# How to pass device id from xamarin.forms to web server on user login

Tags: android, laravel, xamarin.forms

I am beginner in Xamarin.forms and would like to know if it is possible to store device id in website database. I have a Laravel project that I load in a webView. I managed to integrate FCM and receive push notifications but I need to send push notifications to specific users. Is it possible to send device id on user login along with username and password? App will not have login itself, only website's login page.
I am searching the net for 3 days already and could not find anything helpfull.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this great tutorial:
https://www.positronx.io/laravel-send-web-push-notification-using-firebase-tutorial/